# Find conserved columns in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, bioconductor

I'd like some help.

I have a matrix with 21 rows and a 
previously undefined number of columns (depend of the input).
Each cell has a number representing how many times the element of the row
appears in a same columns.

```
structure(c(7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 29L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
35L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 28L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 29L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 28L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 22L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
28L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 32L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 31L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 35L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
21L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 29L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 31L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
28L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 28L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), .Dim = c(22L, 
36L), .Dimnames = list(c("-", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", 
"Y"), NULL))
```

This is a `MultipleAlignment` object from `Biostring` package, but I don't care about the type of object, I may convert it any time.

I'd like to extract a matrix from this one where I have only columns
where a same element (a row) represent x% of the column.
Something like `value on cell / sum values in a column`.
for example, on column 6 the `W` appear 29 times where the sum of values in this column is 39, it means more than 74% or 0,74 (frequency),so if my cutoff is `cutoff >= 0.7` it is included on final matrix.

There are a easy way to do this.

I prefer `BioConductor` packages (as `Biostring`), `tidyverse` or even `R base`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option, where `mat` is the input you provided: a 22x36 matrix

```
thres <- 0.7
out <- mat[, colSums((mat / colSums(mat)) >= thres) > 0]
```

You'd drop three columns

```
dim(out)
# [1] 22 33
```

The idea is to divide the matrix by the column sums and check whether the result is greater then or equal to 0.7. This gives a logical matrix. We can then calculate column sums another time and keep only those columns for which we have at least one `TRUE`.

---

Another idea using `apply` as provided by @d.b. in the comments

```
mat[, apply(mat, 2, function(x) any((x/sum(x)) > thres))]
```

Comment: @d.b Included your suggestion. Thanks